# A recursive formula for a certain family of integrals

Tags: integration, calculus

Any tips on how to do this? Sorry about the title.

> Let $$I_n = \int_0^1\frac{x^{2n+1}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\;dx.$$ 
>   Show that $$I_n = \frac{2n}{2n+1}I_{n-1}.$$

([Original scan of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36v3g.jpg))

Comment: And I have tried integration by parts!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=\sin t$. *Then* integrate by parts. You should get your integral to be

> $$I_n=\int\limits_0^{\pi /2} {{{\sin }^{2n + 1}}tdt} $$

You *will* have to use that $\cos ^2t=1-\sin ^2t$.

Comment: Thanks! I've managed it now.

Comment: @Oliver Nice. Then you might be interested in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494776/elementary-proof-for-lim-n-to-infty-dfracnennn-infty/494802#494802).