# Limit of the function with factorial and exponential

Tags: limits

Evaluate the limit
$$\large{\lim_{n\to \infty} {e^n n!\over n^n}}$$

Does the limit have a defined value?
If yes then please provide me a solution to it.

Comment: Duplicate: [$\lim\limits_{n \to\infty}\dfrac{e^nn!}{n^n}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/494776/201168). (*Found using [Approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/)*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a_n:=\frac{n^n}{e^nn!}\implies\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)^n}{e^{n+1}(n+1)!}\frac{e^nn!}{n^n}=\frac1e\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\frac1{(n+1)}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac1ee\cdot0=0$$

Thus, the positive series $\;\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\;$ converges by D'Alembert's test, so

$$a_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\implies\frac1{a_n}=\frac{e^nn!}{n^n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty$$

Comment: good 2 see something other than stirling

Comment: That was perfect! Thanks a ton.

Comment: This is wrong, we have $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{e^{n+1}(n+1)!} \frac{e^n n!}{n^n} = \frac{(n+1)^n}{e^{n+1} n!} \frac{e^n n!}{n^n} = \frac{1}{e}\biggl(1 + \frac{1}{n}\biggr)^n \to 1.$$ The ratio test is inconclusive. In fact, the series is divergent, since $a_n \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$. (cc @AbhishekBhat)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

When you have problems involving factorials, Stirling approximation is very useful. A simple form is $$n! \simeq  \sqrt{2\pi n}\Big(\frac{n}{e}\Big)^n$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Havent heard bout the formula.. Nyways thank you...Let me try it from here.

Comment: @AbhishekBhat. It is a very classical and very useful and simple approximation. There are more accurate approximations but this one is so simple. Keep it in your memory for ever since you will use it a lot with success !

Answer (score 0):

yes it does. The easiest way to see it is to use Stirling's formula for $n!$. Another way is to write $\frac{1 \cdot 2 \ldots n}{n \cdot n \ldots n}$ and take the upper bound. Can you handle from here?

Comment: Okay let me try solving it from here. Thank you btw.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\dfrac{e^n\cdot n!}{n^n} \approx \sqrt{2\pi n}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

[Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) states  that
$$n!\sim n^ne^{-n}\sqrt{2n\pi}.$$
I think from here you can do