# Limit of $ \frac{e^k k!}{k^k} $

Tags: limits, factorial

According to WolframAlpha we should have

$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{a^k k!}{k^k} = \infty
$$

whenever $a \geq e$. I know how to show that the limit is 0 when $a < e$ and that the limit is $\infty$ when $a > e$, but I struggle with the case $a = e$. Setting

$$
f(k) = \frac{e^k k!}{k^k}
$$

we have that

$$
\frac{f(k+1)}{f(k)} = e\left(1 - \frac{1}{k + 1}\right)^k
$$

converges to 1, but this is not sufficient.

Comment: You can try ratio test, algebra comes out ok

Comment: Ratio test yields no conclusion.

Comment: Yes, I realize that now, because of that e-power ...

Comment: Duplicate: [$\lim\limits_{n \to\infty}\dfrac{e^nn!}{n^n}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/494776/201168). (*Found using [Approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/)*)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**

You can use Stirling formula:

$$n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n} \frac {n^n}{e^n}.$$

Comment: Indeed, it is immediately clear from this formula. Now, do you have a good reference to a proof of this?

Comment: @Bib-lost some proofs are given on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Comment: Only in french... But like @Omnomnomnom said, you will find many on the Internet.

Comment: French is okay for me. I am working through the Wikipedia proofs but they all require something I have never heard of.

Comment: @Bib-lost Then I like [this one](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~gelineau/devagreg/Formule_Stirling.pdf).

Comment: @E.Joseph so do I!

Answer (score 5):

Starting from your
$$ \dfrac{f(k+1)}{f(k)} = e \left( 1 - \dfrac{1}{k+1}\right)^k $$
take logarithms:
$$ \log f(k+1) - \log f(k) = 1 + k \log \left(1 - \dfrac{1}{k+1}\right) $$
Now if $1/2 < a < 1$,  there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\log(1-t) \ge -t - a t^2$ for $0 < t< \epsilon$, and thus for sufficiently large $k$,
$$\eqalign{ \log f(k+1) - \log f(k) &\ge 1 + k \left(- \dfrac{1}{k+1} - \dfrac{a}{(k+1)^2} \right)\cr &= \dfrac{(1-a)k+1}{(k+1)^2}\cr }$$
Now use the fact that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{k}{(k+1)^2} = \infty$.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need Stirling's formula, you can use easier estimates, e.g. [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Rate_of_growth_and_approximations_for_large_n):

We have:

$$
\log n! = \sum_{x=1}^n \log x
$$

so, looking at the graph of $\log x$ we can easy bound it below and above by integrals:

$$
\int_1^n \log x \, dx \leq \sum_{x=1}^n \log x \leq \int_0^n \log (x+1) \, dx
$$

which gives us the estimate

$$
n\log\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)+1 \leq \log n! \leq (n+1)\log\left( \frac{n+1}{e} \right) + 1
$$

so

$$
e\left(\frac ne\right)^n \leq n! \leq e\left(\frac{n+1}e\right)^{n+1}
$$

This is clearly weaker estimate than Stirling's formula, but will work well enough for your problem.

Comment: I agree with all of your calculations, but how does this solve my initial problem? It only shows that the limit is at least $e$ ...