# Show that the following sequence converges for $ 0 < a < e $ and diverges for $ a \ge e$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have this question which I'm having trouble solving, can I use some help? :)

Show that the following sequence converges for $ 0 < a < e $ and diverges for $ a \ge e$:

$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a^nn!}{n^n} $

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is Stirling's formula known?

Comment: No, haven't heard of it :\

Comment: Try to find the [radius of convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence) as $R = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left| \dfrac{c_n}{c_{n+1}} \right|,$ where $c_n=\dfrac{n!}{n^n}.$

Comment: Or even better : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177538/finding-the-convergence-interval-of-sum-limits-n-0-infty-fracnxnnn

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: Use the Ratio Test.

Note that $$\left|\frac{a^{n+1}(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\cdot \frac{n^n}{a^n\cdot n!}\right| = a\cdot\frac{n+1}{n}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}.$$

Hint 2: Show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n+1} = 1/e.$

Comment: What if the limit is $1$?

Comment: By Stirling's theorem, $n! \approx c\sqrt{n}(n/e)^n$, so $e^n n!/n^n \approx c \sqrt{n}$ so the sum diverges. This can be proved by reasonably elementary means using the properties of log and exp.