# Spivak chapter 27 problem 3 (ii)

Tags: sequences-and-series

The chapter is about complex series and the question is to determine the radius of convergence using the root test:

Root test: the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converges if $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (|a_{n}|)^{\frac{1}{n}}=r<1$$

The series to be determined is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n!z^{n}}{n^{n}}$$

Using the root test one obtains $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}|z|}{n}$$

Now from problem 13 of chapter 22 the following result is obtained $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}=\frac{1}{e}$$

It seems to me then that series converges for $\frac{|z|}{e}<1$ so the radius of convergence is $e$

However it is stated in "Answers to selected problems" that the radius of convergence is $\infty$ which is why I wonder if there is something wrong to my approach or if the "solution manual" is wrong?

Ps. It is the 3:rd edition [image: the answer from the book]

Comment: I think you're right and solution manual wrong. Though you also needed the version of root test saying if limit is $> 1$,  then the series diverges (so that your computation shows radius of convergence is no more than $e$).

Comment: The answer book has radius  of convergence e. Also it is revised in the 4th edition; however, the 4th edition introduces a new typo in the selected answers.

Comment: @dunham it is wierd because in the book this problem is labeled 3.(ii) however in the answers it is labeled 3.(iii). I have double checked to make sure they are talking about the same sum . I will add a picture of the solution in the book for reference

Comment: @mathworker21 thanks! I did somewhat hastily write it down here and forgot that part.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177538/finding-the-convergence-interval-of-sum-limits-n-0-infty-fracnxnnn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An other method.
If

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}|=R$$
then it is the radius.

in your case, the limit is

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(1+\frac 1n)^n=e=R$$

Answer (score 0):

These are the revisions in the 4th edition:

Problem in the 4th edition:

[image]

Selected solutions in the 4th edition:

[image]

Answer book solution to 3rd and 4th editions:

[image]