# How do I prove whether the series converges when $a_n = \frac {n! e^n}{n^n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The series $\sum a_n$ is the series I get when analyzing the endpoint of a power series, so the ratio test is out of the question. How else can I find whether this particular series converges?

Comment: Keyword: [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) (+limit comparison test).

Comment: WIthout using it? This is supposed to be a very basic calculus class so I'm forbidden from using it

Comment: So then, again, why is the ratio test out of the question?

Comment: because it's the endpoint of the radius of convergence of a power series. The ratio test yields 1

Comment: Admittedly, but you have [the usual extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#Extensions_for_L_=_1).

Comment: and how do I use that extension?

Comment: **Voting to reopen:** The answers to the question linked (for those having marked it as duplicate) use Stirling's or more advanced ideas, which the OP said was not allowed. *(Maybe be less quick to close?)*

Comment: For what it's worth, the OP seems to have accepted the duplicate. Also, this is a question that has been asked a lot of times already (see the list of questions linked to the duplicate target), and it's getting hard to compare all the answers. I think it would be better to keep this closed, but I admit that I may not have chosen the best target (and now the target has been closed as a duplicate itself).

Comment: @ClementC.For what it's worth , the duplicate of the current duplicate, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177538/finding-the-convergence-interval-of-sum-limits-n-0-infty-fracnxnnn has the simple solution via the series embedded in an Edit of the question itself

Answer (score 0):

**What's below is overkill, as pointed out in the comments.** Indeed, once it's established that 
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
= \frac{e}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}} > 1
$$
then it's clear that the sequence $(a_n)_n$ is inctreasing. Therefore, $a_n \not\to 0$, and the series $\sum_n a_n$ trivially diverges by the limit test.

---

Since [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) is not allowed*, let's try extensions of the ratio test.

Since
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{(n+1)e\cdot  n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}
= \frac{e\cdot  n^n}{(n+1)^{n}}
= \frac{e}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}}
$$
we have
$$\begin{align*}
n\left( \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} -1 \right)
&= e^{-1}n\left( \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} - e\right)
= e^{-1}n\left( e^{n \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)} - e\right)\\
&= e^{-1}n\left( e^{n(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{2n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right))} - e\right)\\
&= e^{-1}n\left( e^{1-\frac{1}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)} - e\right)
= n\left( e^{-\frac{1}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)} - 1\right)\\
&= n\left( -\frac{1}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)\\
&\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \boxed{-\frac12} < 1
\end{align*}$$
so the series diverges by [Raabe's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#2._Raabe's_test).

---

${}^\ast$ Of course, if you want to use it: $n!\displaystyle\operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} {\sqrt{2\pi n}}\frac{n^n}{e^n}$, so
$$
a_n \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} {\sqrt{2\pi n}}
$$
and the series $\sum_n a_n$ (of positive terms) diverges by the limit test.

Comment: sorry but raabe's test and the other approximation are also out of the question

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio That's fair.It'd be worth editing your question to make that clear (esp. as otherwise, it's likely to get closed as it's smilar to other questions without those constraints).

Comment: In Stirling, $\sqrt{2\pi n}$ is in the numerator, not the denominator. Here, $a_{n+1}/a_n>1$, so it's apparent the series diverges. A more challenging series (again restricting to "elementary" methods) is $\sum_n\frac{n^n}{e^nn!}$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown My bad yes, the Stirling approach is even more obvious than expected. And yes, knowing that $(1+1/n)^n < e$, Raabe's test and the ratio test are both unnecessary -- the ratio is greater that one, so the sequence $(a_n)_n$ is increasing, and therefore the series diverges by the limit test.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I edited my answer accordingly.